# Why does fs::read_dir() returns an iterator over Result<DirEntry, Error>

Tags: error-handling, rust

This code prints a couple of `Ok`s on my system:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    fs::read_dir("/home").unwrap().for_each(|e| {
        println!("{:?}", e);
    });
}
```

I need to `unwrap` the `DirEntry` elements before using them.

The documentation of [`fs::read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) states:

> Returns an iterator over the entries within a directory.
>
> The iterator will yield instances of [`io::Result<DirEntry>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html). New errors may be encountered after an iterator is initially constructed.

What kind of error is the documentation talking about? Is it safe to `unwrap` the `Result`?

Answer (score 7):

`fs::read_dir` may encounter errors when opening the directory, for instance if the directory does not exist or the user does not have permission to read it. However, even after opening the directory, any number of errors may occur:

- the directory could have been deleted;
- the permissions of the directory may have changed;
- the underlying storage medium could have an IO error (e.g. hard drive failure);
- the directory could be on a removable drive that was removed (or a network drive that was disconnected);
- or any other error that the operating system may give for the operation

It's not possible to return this errors in the result given by `fs::read_dir`; instead, we must give them in the iterator itself. That's the reason why the iterator yields items of type `Result<DirEntry, std::io::Error>`, so that the programmer has the possibility to catch and handle these errors.

---

As for if it's safe to `unwrap` the result, it's only really safe if you know with certainty that the result is not an error (otherwise your code will panic). In many contexts, such as when prototyping, you may not care if your code crashes, but when writing proper applications in Rust you should avoid `unwrap` and instead rely on proper error handling and error propagation.

This is a pattern I typically use when working with iterators that may yield errors:

```rust
use std::{fs, io};

fn read_dir_and_do_stuff() -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    for entry in fs::read_dir("/home")? {
        //                            ^
        //               v------------'---  automatically return errors
        let entry = entry?;

        // ... do something
        println!("{:?}", entry);
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = read_dir_and_do_stuff() {
         // handle error
         println!("Error occurred: {}", err);
         return;
    }
}
```

You may also use methods such as [`Iterator::try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold), [`Iterator::try_for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_for_each) and [`Iterator::collect::<Result<..., E>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) if you want to use chaining instead of `for in`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look under the hood via `strace` shows the following (after some trimming):

```
$ strace ./target/debug/readdir-test
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
getdents64(3, /* 4 entries */, 32768)   = 104
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So readdir requires multiple system calls. Checking `man getdents64` tells us this is linux-specific, the POSIX API is `readdir`, its manpage in turn says:

> The readdir() function returns a pointer to a dirent structure representing the next directory entry in the directory stream pointed to by dirp.  It returns NULL on reaching the end of the directory stream or if an error occurred.

What this tells us is that walking a directory is performed in multiple steps, where each step could return an error. Thus the correct way to expose this in rust is returning `Result` for each step.